# `threadsafe!` method missing in rails

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

To enable multithreading in rails I have set `config.threadsafe!` in `development.rb`.

I get an error saying:

```
'method_missing': undefined method `threadsafe!' (NoMethodError)
```

I am using rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.0.0. Please anyone help me with reason and way to come out of this.

`development.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.threadsafe! 
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Error:

```
/home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined
 method `threadsafe!' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000482a6c8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config/environments/development.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/gayithri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/gayithri/workspace/ThreadDemo/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: could you show us the code in your development.rb, and the full error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`config.threadsafe!` is no longer necessary and was removed. Rails is threadsafe by default. All it did on this config option turned out to be also valid for multiprocess single threaded deployment, so now it just does this operations.

[Removing config.threadsafe!](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html)

Comment: if config.threadsafe! is removed then how can i enable multithreading in rails?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails. Its entirely the matter of your application server. The most popular  one in the Ruby world is Puma. Passender Enterprise and Rainbows also support multithreading. Unicorn and standard Passenger in contrast do not.  A lot of people switch to JRuby for real concurrency, which allows you to deploy on Java app server. Tourquebox is their first choise recommendation

Comment: Found it helpful.Thanks a ton.